# Oracle Apex JavaScript Set Value not working

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex

I have a page with 2 page items:

P4_FILE_BLOB
A file Upload Item

P4_FILE_NAME
A blank text field Item

The File Upload item has a dynamic action on Change (dynamic scope / no client side condition / event: change) with the following JS:

```
var fp = $("#P4_FILE_BLOB");
var lg = fp[0].files.length;
var items = fp[0].files;
if (lg > 0) { 
        for (var i = 0; i < lg; i++) {
            var fileName = items[i].name;
            apex.item( "P4_FILE_NAME" ).setValue( fileName, null, true ); 
    }
}
```

It doesn't work, once I use the File Upload item (look for an item / select it) it doesn't do anything. Text item remains blank.
Why?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code ? The file name is part of the upload process, there should be no reason to set that separately. Have a look at the sample file upload app.